# Error while exporting GeoJSON from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, export

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" test.geojson -t_srs EPSG:4326 PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=sp_join port=5432" -sql 'select gid, geom from test'
```

I am using the following code in `ogr2ogr` to export a table from PostGIS to GeoJSON, but get the following errors:

```
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
ERROR 1: Reading EWKB with 4-dimensional coordinates (XYZM) is not supported
```

How can I avoid 4-dimensional coordinates?

Comment: use `-dim XY` or similar

Comment: thanks.  where would that go in the ogr2ogr request?

Comment: anywhere near the end; see usage for [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove unwanted ordinates with any of:

- [ST_Force2D](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force2D.html), which drops the Z and M ordinates,
- [ST_Force3D](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_3D.html), which drops the M ordinate, and
- [ST_Force3DM](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_3DM.html), which drops the Z ordinate.

So you could modify your `-sql` argument like this:

```
-sql 'select gid, st_force2d(geom) from test'
```

Comment: thanks, how would that be included in the code? I try `select gid, geom from test; ST_Force2D(geom)` and get a syntax error

Comment: Do not change the correct syntax that is used in the answer.